# error in implementation of promise in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, promise

I am trying to learn the concept of promise and implement in angular. Here is my code in [stackblit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-juqccv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). What I am trying to achieve is , I have want to show the array whenever it is assigned with any value using promise in angular.

My Html Code is :

```
<h2>Array values</h2>
<p *ngIf="show">
  <span *ngFor="let values of filter">
    {{values}}
  </span>
</p>
```

My TS file is :

```
filter = [];
show = false;
ngOnInit() {
  this.showArray();
}
showArray() {
    var a = new Promise(resolve=>{
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.filter = [3, 4, 4]
        resolve('resolved');
      }, 0);

    });

    a.then(function() {
      this.show= true;
    })
}
```

Whenever my array is assigned with any values(which might be from a remote API), I want to set the variable **show** to true. I am not getting the result. I have gone through many examples related to promise but couldn't found a working example of promise in this fashion.

Comment: Everything seems to be fine. Just change your then block to like -> a.then((func) => {
      this.show= true;
    })

Comment: How this is a duplicate ??

Comment: It is a duplicate because it is the same problem, with the same solutions, as in the reference post. That question is asked every day on the Angular forum, and doesn't need more duplicate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with -

```
a.then(() => {
  this.show= true;
})
```

you need to use **arrow** function instead of existing one.

If you are using this piece of code -

```
a.then(function() {
  this.show= true;
})
```

this will not bind to `show` variable which is of class level but template binding is done with class level variable, that is why existing code is not working.

<kbd>[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejpmoc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)</kbd>

Comment: worked perfectly . thanx

Comment: Does this answer deserve one upvote? :P

Comment: It certainly does. :)